# ASPNET MVC 4 and mustache

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, mustache

I'm writing an ASPNET MVC 4 application and I'm trying to use mustache templates.
My problem is that I always get an 404 for the file and I don't realize what the problem is.
Any ideas?

I'm creating a hidden control with the url in index.html like this:

```
@Html.Hidden("urlMustacheTemplates", Url.Content("~/Views/Templates/"))
```

then in a javascript file

```
$.get($("#urlMustacheTemplates").val() + "main.mustache", function (template) {
    var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
    output = $.mustache(template, data);
});
```

I put a

```
debugger;
```

in the javascript and I see the url is correct, my file in

```
/Views/Templates/main.mustache
```

But I get a 404 file not found.

Thanks in advance! Guillermo.

Comment: Sounds like some sort of routing problem. You might want to check your routes are setup too handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take your templates folder out of the Views Folder and put it in the root or in an Assets Folder.

/Assets/Templates/main.mustache

or

/Templates/main.mustache

Comment: Once you have moved it out of your Views folder, start the application (F5) then in the browser manually go to /Assets/Templates/main.mustache  What is the response?  It should download the mustache file.

Comment: HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

Comment: Are you using IIS or the built in Visual Studio server?  It works for me in the Visual Studio 2012 server.  In IIS you will probably have to add a MIME type to serve this kind of file.